# Enable cleartext authentication for Sequel Pro on Mac OS to mysql?

Tags: macos, mysql, sequel-pro

I am trying to connect to mysql database from ***Sequel Pro*** on ***Mac OS***.

How would I enable cleartext authentication with Sequel Pro for connecting to mysql?

Comment: user3805033 - Did you find my answer below of any helpfulness with this issue I tried to help you with long ago, or not? I know it's been awhile so wanted to kindly ask you for an update as I don't see any comments or anything like that either so wanted to follow up on this old post just in case.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Cleartext Client-Side Authentication Plugin<sup>[1]</sup>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cleartext-authentication-plugin.html) ***a client-side authentication plugin is available that sends the password to the server without hashing or encryption. This plugin is built into the MySQL client library.***

Also [The PAM Authentication Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html) indicates that ***<sup>1.)</sup> the PAM authentication plugin has been tested on Linux and Mac OS X***, and that ***<sup>2.)</sup> the PAM authentication plugin is an extension included in MySQL Enterprise Edition, a commercial product.***

I found this [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1166938) which may or may not apply in your case but I'll provide as FYI at least.

---

> ### [Installing the 6.5.1.3.1 Pam Authentication Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html#pam-authentication-plugin-installation)
>
> The PAM authentication plugin must be located in the MySQL plugin
>   directory (the directory named by the [`plugin_dir`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_plugin_dir) system variable). If
>   necessary, set the value of [`plugin_dir`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_plugin_dir) at server startup to tell the
>   server the plugin directory location.
>
> To enable the plugin, start the server with the [`--plugin-load`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_plugin-load) option.
>   For example, put the following lines in your my.cnf file. If library
>   files have a suffix different from .so on your system, substitute the
>   correct suffix.
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> plugin-load=authentication_pam.so
> ```
>
> To verify plugin installation, examine the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/plugins-table.html)
>   table or use the [`SHOW PLUGINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-plugins.html) statement (see [Section 5.5.3, “Obtaining
>   Server Plugin Information”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/obtaining-plugin-information.html)). For example:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS
>     -> WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'authentication%';
> +--------------------+---------------+
> | PLUGIN_NAME        | PLUGIN_STATUS |
> +--------------------+---------------+
> | authentication_pam | ACTIVE        |
> +--------------------+---------------+
> ```
>
> To associate a MySQL account with the PAM plugin, use the plugin name
>   `authentication_pam` in the `IDENTIFIED WITH` clause of [`CREATE USER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html) or
>   [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) statement that creates the account
>
> <sub>[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html#pam-authentication-plugin-installation)</sub>

You can see the **6.5.1.3.2 Using the PAM Authentication Plugin** section just beneath that (the source you read above on the actual site) for the usage instructions for your need with this plugin.

---

> ### Full Detail
>
> ### [Cleartext Client-Side Authentication Plugin<sup>[1]</sup>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cleartext-authentication-plugin.html)
>
> As of MySQL 5.5.10, a client-side authentication plugin is available
>   that sends the password to the server without hashing or encryption.
>   This plugin is built into the MySQL client library.
>
> With native MySQL authentication, the client performs one-way hashing
>   on the password before sending it to the server. This enables the
>   client to avoid sending the password in clear text. See [Section
>   6.1.2.4, "Password Hashing in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-hashing.html)".
>   However, because the hash algorithm is one way, the original password
>   cannot be recovered on the server side.
>
> One-way hashing cannot be done for authentication schemes that require
>   the server to receive the password as entered on the client side. In
>   such cases, the `mysql_clear_password` client-side plugin can be used
>   to send the password to the server in clear text. There is no
>   corresponding server-side plugin. Rather, the client-side plugin can
>   be used by any server-side plugin that needs a clear text password.
>   (The PAM authentication plugin is one such; see [Section 6.5.1.3, "The
>   PAM Authentication
>   Plugin"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/secure-connections.html).)
>
> For general information about pluggable authentication in MySQL, see
>   [Section 6.3.6, "Pluggable
>   Authentication"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pluggable-authentication.html).
>
> > ### **NOTE**
> >
> > *Sending passwords in clear text may be a security problem in some configurations. To avoid problems if there is any possibility that the
> >     password would be intercepted, clients should connect to MySQL Server
> >     using a method that protects the password. Possibilities include SSL
> >     (see Section 6.4, “Using Secure Connections”), IPsec, or a private
> >     network.*
>
> As of MySQL 5.5.27, to make inadvertent use of this plugin less
>   likely, it is required that clients explicitly enable it. This can be
>   done several ways:
>
> - Set the `LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN` environment variable to a value that begins with 1, Y, or y. This enables the plugin for all
>     client connections.
> - The [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html), [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html),
>     and
>     [mysqlslap](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlslap.html)
>     client programs support an `--enable-cleartext-plugin` option that
>     enables the plugin on a per-invocation basis.
> - The [mysql_options()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-options.html)
>     C API function supports a `MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN` option that
>     enables the plugin on a per-connection basis. Also, any program that
>     uses libmysqlclient and reads option files can enable the plugin by
>     including an `enable-cleartext-plugin` option in an option group read
>     by the client library.
>
> <sub>[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cleartext-authentication-plugin.html)</sub>